How is formula of the volume of trirectangular tetrahedron $\frac{A\times B\times C}{6}$?
I am just trying to understand where I am wrong.
Let a cuboid be constructed with sides $A \hat{i},B \hat{j}, C \hat{k} $
Then the volume of the cuboid is $ A\times B\times C$
Trirectangular tetrahedron is half of the cuboid so it should have a volume of
$$ \frac{A\times B\times C}{2}$$
Please tell where I am wrong.

My friend (who says I can "post this without credit") made this model in Desmos 3D: https://www.desmos.com/3d/rr1ctkoc5p It depicts two trirectangular tetrahedra in a cuboid, showing that there's still plenty of space left over. (Doesn't work on mobile.)


Trirectangular tetrahedron is half of the cuboid

No it's not.  Here is a picture of the tetrahedron and the rest of the cuboid

Even without calculation it should be clear that the tetrahedron is not half the cuboid.
With this picture, it is at least plausible that the terahedron has 1/6 the volume of the cuboid, and observing the general formula that the volume of a tetrahedron is 1/3 × base × height, and the base is 1/2 × length × width, leads to the formula that you give.

Thankyou I get it now for some reason I felt that It should be half of rectangle but now its clear thanks
